# Is this an intuitive way to understand why the expected value of a geometric distribution is 1/p

Tags: probability, statistics

The expected value for the number of trials necessary for a success is essentially the same as asking when the expected value of the binomial distribution is equal to 1. With that, we set np where n is the number of trials and p is the probability of success equal to 1. So np = 1, therefore n = 1/p.

Comment: If , say , the probability of success is $0.02$ What would you INTUITIVELY expect how many trials we need in average to have a success ? I think , you would guess $50$ which is in fact the correct result.

Comment: I’m asking if my “proof” is correct.

Comment: Peter's answer was yes. How you express that essentially, intuitively or in a "proof" is up to you.